# Как можно получить ближайшие точки в радиусе например 5 км. у построенного маршрута?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть задача, пользователь строит маршрут указывая начальную и конечную точку. После того как маршрут построен, выводятся ближайшие точки в радиусе 5 км. на этом пути.
Подскажите алгоритм и какие функции использовать для этого. Как построить маршрут там по моему всё понятно, но как получить ближайшие точки в радиусе у построенного маршрута - не очень.

Хочу сделать так:
После построения маршрута строю Polyline по отрезкам этого маршрута.
Потом хотел окружить этот отрезок полигоном и те метки которые попадают в этот полигон я показываю (например через searchInside). Но пока не получается окружить ломанную Polyline полигоном. Может есть какие-то методы для этого ?

Comment: *"выводятся ближайшие точки в радиусе 5 км"* - что такое *точки* в вашем понимании?

Comment: В тегах яндекс Карты, вам алгоритм нужен или реализация от яндекса?

Comment: Под точками я понимаю метки Placemarks которые отмечены на карте.